# Android custom spinner need to change background colour

Tags: android, sdk, spinner

I know this subject has been covered numerous times before but I struggling to get it to work with my custom spinner .

As I have a custom spinner setup to show graphics and text as per this tutorial :
http://android-er.blogspot.sk/2010/12/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html

and that is fine, however if I change the background colour using the spinners reference in java mypsinner.setBackground(COLOR.LTGRAY) and then do the same for the custom row , row.setBackground(COLOR.LTGRAY) it does change both to the same colour but then I loose the spinner effect where it appears 2D instead of being flat and the drop down arrow also disappears. Am I having to do a graphics for this instead?

Comment: Right I have changed the spinner to have a Light Gray graphic now but even though that it the case, if I set the row to be Light Gray (because I want to use that as the background colour for the list) it still overrides the spinner graphic

Answer (score 0):

You lose those details because default spinner backgrounds are detailed nine-patch images with shadows, bevel and arrow etc., not colors.

Comment: Ok, the main goal here is to change the background of the rows which are displayed when the spinner is clicked. However If I just change the row colour this then affects the spinner , so lets say I leave the spinner as it is , choose the colour of the row as black, then a black box appears within the spinner, anyway around this?